# combine two or more navs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to create a three-panel layout:

- left: a list of items generated with ng-repeat (ie: group1, group2, group3...)
- top: a couple of buttons for each group-page (ie: home, browse, users,...)
- right: the content panel

Now, there a re a couple of problems that I'm running into:

- I want the user to always have one group selected, and this should be expressed in the url (/group/:groupId). This groupId can only be known after getting the groups from the backend database, but I still want this to be the default page. In other words the website's homepage should have a groupId in it, depending on the current user.
- When a user clicks on of the top panel links, he should be taken to that group-specific page (/group/:groupId:/home)
- When a user clicks on of the group links in the left panel, he should be taken to the currently selected page of that group (ie: if the user was at /group/1/home and clicks on group2, he should be taken to /group/2/home, if he was at /group/1/browse and clicks on group2, he should be taken to /group/2/browse)

Anyone got a clue as how to achieve this behavior? I've been trying to wrap my head around this but can't seem to find a good way to achieve this. Please post and ask if you need clarification.

EDIT: I'm using UI-router

Comment: You should look at using the UI-Router instead of the built-in Angular `ngRoute` https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I do use ui-router. Edited

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about tutoring

Comment: If this question is indeed about tutoring, please provide a link to a tutorial that explains how to achieve this behavior. I've been working with ui-router for a while now and I can honestly say I know how the basics work, but this particular usecase doesn't seem to be covered by that.

Answer (score 1):

In case it could be of use to someone:

I solved this by:

- adding a global resolve that loads the user's groups.
- providing a service to manage the current group-state
- building all references to the homepage using the groupId in that service
- not relying on href, but using ui-sref (as intended by ui-router) as described here: [ui-router wiki: ui-sref](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref)